# How to check if document was inserted or updated via firestore set with {merge:true}

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I use `set()` with `{merge:true}` option to upsert to Firestore certain data I receive daily.

This used to be fine but now I need to check whether a document was **inserted or updated** by this call.

I know that I could manually retrieve data first, check whether a document exists, then call update or add accordingly,

but I'd rather avoid the additional reading cost if possible since I receive a lot of data in a short period of time with limited server resources.

**Is there a (hidden) value that shows whether a document was inserted or updated via set() {merge: true}?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know that I could manually retrieve data first, check whether a document exists, then call update or add accordingly.

That's what you should do. You have to check first and then perform the operation.

> Is there a (hidden) value that shows whether a document was inserted or updated via set() {merge: true}?

No, there is not.

Please note that the `set()` function with the `{merge:true}` option, always changes the behavior of the regular `set()` function calls to only replace the values that are passed as arguments. Fields omitted from the `set()` call will remain **untouched**.

Remember, when using `set()` without `{merge:true}`, it will always create the document, if the document **doesn't** exist. If the document **does** exist, its contents will be overwritten with the newly provided data, unless you specify that the data should be merged into the existing document using `{merge:true}`.

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't find official comment that such value DOESN'T exist and was wandering whether there are some hidden features that experienced devs might know. I guess it is what it is!