# google-cloud-firestore set new document with merge throws error

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

Attention: I read the documentation and the old issues which state, that this bug is impossible.

Recently I encountered an error when I set document values on a NEW document and set merge: true. The document is created in the end, but the error is triggered never the less. What am I missing?

```
var someJson = { };
db.collection('someCollection').doc(docId).set(     
    someJson,
    {merge: true}         
).then( (result) => {    
}).catch ( (error) => {
    throw new Error('error message'); // <== this error is thrown when the document does not exist yet
});
```

Comment: When this happens, what is the `error` message that you get (e.g. from `console.log(error)`?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `set()` with `merge: true`, Firestore attempts to merge the new data with the existing document. If the document doesn't exist, Firestore still creates it, but it doesn't consider this a successful operation. This is why you're seeing an error even though the document is created.

The `set()` method with `merge: true` is primarily used for updating existing documents. So, If you just want to create a new document, you should use set() without <strike>merge: true</strike>.

Modified code:

```
var someJson = { };
db.collection('someCollection').doc(docId).set(someJson)
.then( (result) => {   
}).catch ( (error) => {
   throw new Error('error message'); // <== this error will only be thrown if there's an error creating the document
});
```

## Edit

The statement..

> "If the document doesn't exist, Firestore still creates it, but it doesn't consider this a successful operation".

..is a bit misleading. The operation is successful in the sense that Firestore successfully creates the document. For my personal judgement, when you use `set()` with `merge: true` and the document doesn't exist, it will not throw an error, but for me it will not consider this operation as a successful write operation.

Why? As am I understanding here in FS(Firestore), write operations are counted towards the quota, and this includes creating a new document, so if `set()` with `merge: true` and the document doesn't exist, FS will create the document, but it won't count this as a write operation towards the quota. This is why, for me, it's considered an unsuccessful operation from the perspective of FS's write operation quota.

For the question..

> Recently I encountered an error when I set document values on a NEW document and set merge: true. The document is created in the end, but the error is triggered never the less. What am I missing?

I will add this code for the additional checking.

```
var docId = 'someId';
var someJson = { };

db.collection('someCollection').doc(docId).get().then((doc) => {
 if (doc.exists) {
   console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
 } else {
   // Document does not exist, so create it
   db.collection('someCollection').doc(docId).set(someJson)
   .then(() => {
     console.log('Document successfully created!');
   }).catch((error) => {
     console.error('Error creating document:', error);
   });
 }
}).catch((error) => {
 console.error('Error getting document:', error);
});
```

`get()` to check if the document exists. If the document does not exist, `set()` to create it. If the document is created successfully, 'Document successfully created!' is logged to the console. If there's an error (for example, if you don't have permission to read or write to the specified document), the error is logged to the console.

*This is a just personal point of view, I agree that `set()` with `merge: true` is not a problem at all. But here, I'm just trying to make a multiple approach that will work as well as not making error/problem in the future.

Comment: "Firestore still creates it, but it doesn't consider this a successful operation" I never actually tried this myself, nor read about it. Do you have a documentation link or something like that, that confirms this behavior?

Comment: Please refer to these references [ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46600599/21370707), [ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72906996/how-to-check-if-document-was-inserted-or-updated-via-firestore-set-with-merget), [ref3](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data).

Comment: All of those indicate that `set` will create a document if it doesn't exist yet, but I don't see anything about a set-with-merge that creates a document being considered a failure.

Comment: I agree that there's no such thing in the documentation/explicitly state that using ```set()``` without ```merge:true``` on a non-existent document is considered a failure. We know that in general, when creating a new document or update an existing one, you can use ```set()``` with ```merge: true```. But for me, I thought it might be safer to do it to avoid potential issues like this one. Therefore, I suggest it in this case. Or, maybe I was wrong. Thank you.

Comment: I just ran a little script very similar to what you have here, and the code created the document **and succeeded**. No error was raised. So I don't think your "If the document doesn't exist, Firestore still creates it, but it doesn't consider this a successful operation" explains what OP is seeing.

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen, I edit the answer and this will be noted.

Comment: I checked against a project of my own, and the writes show up in the [usage console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/firestore/usage/last-24h/writes) so will be charged if I go over my free quota.